# estimation of the distribution of the difference of ordered samples

Tags: probability

I came across an interesting problem listed below:

Consider an interval from 0 to 1 with ten uniformly distributed points in it. What is the distribution of the difference between the 6th and the 5th smallest point?

I have a strong feeling that the distribution of difference is the same for all consecutive pairs but I have no idea how to prove it. Could anyone pls help me with this, thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Order_statistics_sampled_from_a_uniform_distribution

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have $n$ points, we want find the distribution of $Y=X_{(i+1)}-X_{(i)}$.

First, notice that the joint distribution of $X_{(i+1)},X_{(i)}$ is
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{n!}{(i-1)!(n-i-1)!}x^{i-1}(1-y)^{n-i-1},0<x<y<1
$$

Then, the distribution of $Y$ is
$$
f_Y(y)=\frac{n!}{(i-1)!(n-i-1)!}\int_0^{1-y}z^{i-1}(1-y-z)^{n-i-1}\,dz=n(1-y)^{n-1},0<y<1
$$